# Importing product to magento using CSV

Tags: csv, magento, import

I am importing products in Magento

System->import->file.csv

The content of file is 
          [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJxoA.png)

But when I click on Check Data Button in Magento 
I got Error: "SKU is empty in rows: 1, 2, 3"
As clear from ScreenShot sku is there in all three rows.
How to get rid of this error
CSV file is in UTF-8

Comment: are you using magento default import ? copy content to new excel sheet and check once......

Answer (score 0):

When product have required fields and you have not filled those values in CSV file then this issue will occur. Also, save the CSV in the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

Try to export products using System->Export. check your exported csv columns with your product csv and re-import it.